# Is it possible to store > 5 billion files on an NTFS formatted drive?

Tags: ntfs

I see two pieces of information everywhere that seem to contradict each other.

They are that there is a limit of `2^32 ~= 4 billion` files that can be stores on an NTFS volume.

But then I always see this addendum that there is an unlimited amount of files supported in directories.

So what exactly is meant here?

Is it possible to store 5 billion files on an NTFS volume if I were to store them in two separate folders (ignoring the implications of performance in the operating system because of this)?

Comment: FAT filesystems have a limit of the number of files in the root directory.  NTFS does not other other than the limit of the total number of files, this might be what was meant.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store 5 billion files.  The [maximum number of files on a *single disk*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134(v=ws.10).aspx) is 4,294,967,295.  This can be in one folder or many.

You might be able to "cheat" by mounting another drive as a folder.  However, I dont know if this would work.

Anyways, that many files would make working with a folder with that many files... really difficult.